# Create vlookup or index match with 2 conditions

Tags: excel, vlookup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKFDX.png)

Hello, how can I create a vlookup or index match to match the exact same date and dimension/page view type? Tried regular vlookup and results do not match with 2nd yellow columns. Also, tried index match and answers #N/A

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Can be done with Index-Match. In columns A through C I have the data. In F & G I've written my criteria, and in H2 my formula is:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1,INDEX((F2=A:A)*(G2=B:B),0,1),0))
```